# How to render the paypal smart buttons through code?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

This is the code to render the paypal smart buttons:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test"></script> 
<script>paypal.Buttons().render('body');</script>
```

But I want to render them through code, so I tried to do this:

```
document.body.innerHTML='<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test"></script>';
paypal.Buttons().render('body');
```

But it didn't work, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding script elements to the DOM will cause them to load asynchronously, not in time for code that immediately follows to make use of them. You need to use a callback function for the script's `onload` event. Here is an example helper function that does so.

```
//Helper function

function loadAsync(url, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src', url); s.onload = callback;
  document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstElementChild);
}

// Usage -- callback is inlined here, but could be a named function

loadAsync('https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD', function() {
  paypal.Buttons({

  // createOrder & onApprove go here and should fetch from a backend
  // do not use actions.order.create or actions.order.capture,
  // they are deprecated and will be sunset

  }).render('body');
});
```

Comment: thank you, it worked. but on one of my pages, it gave this error:

    Refused to load the script 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' blob

do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Change the script-src HTTP header served by that page

Comment: sorry, how to do it?

Comment: Depends on however you are serving that page

Comment: my code is on a userscript that is running on a userscript manager on a page. I dont know how to achieve that, can you tell me please?

Comment: For a userscript you can try `@require`

Comment: sorry, I dont understand. can you tell me how the code is please?

Comment: using @require to import the paypal script is not working for me, if that is what must be done.

Comment: Well I have no idea if you are doing it correctly, but adding a payment button with a userscript seems a silly idea anyway

Comment: ok, but please can you tell me how to achieve your solution "Change the script-src HTTP header served by that page" ? It's for my business that Im doing this

Comment: Webservers set HTTP headers