# jQuery. Deferred exception: window.paypal is undefined

Tags: jquery, paypal

I have taken the Standard Payment templates off paypal/github to add paypal to my test site. For the life of me, I can't figure out why window.paypal is undefined. This code is only called after $.ready, so I know the DOM is updated.

**HTML**

```
...
<div id="paypal-button-container">
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=blah&currency=USD"></script>
<script src="../scripts/paypal.js"></script>
```

**CLIENT PAYPAL.JS SCRIPT**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log('guss: ',guss);
  console.log('window.guss: ',window.guss);
  console.dir(window);
  console.dir(window.paypal);
  window.paypal.Buttons({      
    async createOrder() {
    ...
```

**RESULTS**

[image]

The paypal documentation says that the paypal object will be inserted into the script, and when I print out the contents of window, it shows that indeed the paypal object is a member (image supplied), yet when I try to use window.paypal it spits out a jQuery.Deferred exception: window.paypal is undefined. Can't figure it out.

Comment: Which file is your **CLIENT SCRIPT** in? Is it `scripts/paypal.js` or something else?

Comment: @Phil - yes, it's the scripts/paypal.js

Comment: Given that first snippet is most definitely **not** HTML, what actually is it? If it's some client-side templating language you will need to wait for it to complete its work

Comment: @Phil. Oh boy. Sorry again. It's jade/pug code. It translates to proper <div>s, <script>s. And no, it gets rendered on the server and sent to client as HTML.

Comment: @Phil - Fixed syntax

Answer (score 0):

"window.paypal is undefined" means the PayPal JS SDK script is not loading successfully, or has not finished loading, at the time other JS attempted to use it.

Comment: But the image shows the the window object has the inner paypal object, and that object has the Buttons/etc objects. The code is all within a $.ready() function. Is there anything else I can do to ensure the load is finished correctly?

Comment: No, it is apparently "undefined" as seen in the screenshot immediately above the last yellow line (helps to use `console.log("window.paypal",window.paypal)` , for clarity).

In the logged window object it shows as defined because it is so at the time you are inspecting that window obj reference. I do not know why your scripts aren't loading synchronously, `defer` attribute for the latter one might work or you can use an onload callback function, or `@paypal/paypal-js`.  Here is an onload example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70131093/how-to-render-the-paypal-smart-buttons-through-code

Comment: Using your code above and still get a race condition. Now it works occasionally but now/then errs with a "zoid destroyed all components", whatever this is.

Comment: That message is not necessarily fatal, but it often means you are doing something like loading the JS SDK twice or rendering buttons to the same location twice. Only do so once.

Comment: Yeah, it always is fatal and it just comes arbitrarily. It's frustrating. I can't imagine it is calling the SDK twice as there is no difference to what I am doing whether the error is generated or it works ocrrectly.

Comment: The most likely explanation remains that you are doing something twice, such as loading the script twice in different places, but without examining the problem there is no way to know